# Android Show Open in Browser inside an Alert

Tags: java, android

I am new into Android Native Development, 
    I want show "Open in Browser" icon inside an alert Message.

```
Case: 
I have a QR code scanned and showing the result in a toast or Alert. 
In the scanned Result, I want to Show up "Open In Browser" with the code result or Alert message
```

The Challenge is I am not able to achieve this functionality.  Kindly let me know how to do this so that I can move further with learning Android.

```
My Manifest goes like this:

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>



And my Result handler
   @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        // Do something with the result here
        Log.v("TAG", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
        Log.v("TAG", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("UTQode Result");
                builder.setMessage(rawResult.getText());
                AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
                alert1.show();
//        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Message",
//                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, rawResult.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
        mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }

I am testing with the above code, but I need to open the alert result and Query it in Browser
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to open the browser by clicking "Open in Browser", you can add a method at pressing a button

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Open in Browser",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    openInBrowser();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
```

If you only want a Icon at the top of the Alert use .setIcon()

Comment: 2 issues Cannot resolve openInBrowser(); and When I Click on No, app get Hanged and  this was about the alert but I even want to open the rawResult which I got in an alert to get opened in another app or browser

Answer (score 0):

Do this in alert dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("UTQode Result");
                builder.setMessage(rawResult.getText());
                builder..setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.your_icon));
                AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
                alert1.show();
```

if you want a button with text "open in browser" do this:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setTitle("UTQode Result");
                        builder.setMessage(rawResult.getText());
                        builder.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.your_icon));
    builder.setPositiveButton("Open in browser", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //do things
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(your result url)));
               }
           });
                        AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
                        alert1.show();
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, this helped me with the alert, but  here is my case When I click on Open in Browser I need to search for the result I got in the Alert.  Case : I get a URL from a QR Code, I get an alert (Now it has Open in Browser:", but when I click on "Open In Browser" The URL I get in my alert (the rarResult) needs to be opened.

Comment: I update the question with the full code that you need.

Comment: Bruno. Thanks for this. It worked. I am working with Package Manager in some time, hope you help me.

Comment: fine that i helped you if helped you acept answer to other people that have the same problema know you found the solution, any question im here to help

Comment: Accepted, How can I open a packagemanager before this? I mean, It directly opens in the default Browser, I want it get opened in the browser I select, Everytime (Everytime).